# Using JavaFX in a headless Raspbian server

Tags: multithreading, servlets, javafx

Based on this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/media-tutorial/playercontrol.htm), I would like to implement a media player website running in a Raspberry Pi connected to an old (but excellent) amplifier/home theather. This means that a servlet (a thread created by a servlet) will play the music and I will control it via Internet.

What I already did and is working? I removed all graphic references (button, panel, etc) from the example and put the resulting code in a thread. When I try to run this on a Tomcat8 in Ubuntu Desktop, everything works fine! But when I try to run it in the Raspberry without GUI, I got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unable to open DISPLAY
```

I know where is the error, but I don't know how to fix it. The problem is in the line below:

```
com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(()->{});
```

Without the line above, I got an error stating that to Toolkit was not initialized.

So,

(1) Is it possible to run JavaFX in a servlet?

(2) How to solve this problem?

Thanks!
Alex